# No detecta variable en Listener Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, web, events

Estaba probando a crear eventos y listeners, y resulta que en el archivo Listener, no me detecta la variable que estoy pasando ($project), imagino que el problema derivará en algo de los archivos "event" y "listener", recién he empezado a toquetear esto, y estoy siguiendo una plataforma de aprendizaje, recalco que he usado el helper $event-> para intentar llegar al $project, que es la variable que no me encuentra, pero no encuentro manera...

**EventServiceProvider.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Auth\Events\Registered;
use Illuminate\Auth\Listeners\SendEmailVerificationNotification;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Support\Providers\EventServiceProvider as ServiceProvider;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Event;

class EventServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * The event listener mappings for the application.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $listen = [
        Registered::class => [
            SendEmailVerificationNotification::class,
        ],  // Creamos nuevo evento, y dentro el listener, los listener responden a los eventos.
        \App\Events\ProjectSaved::class => [
            \App\Listeners\OptimizeProjectImage::class
        ]
    ];

    /**
     * Register any events for your application.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        parent::boot();

        //
    }
}
```

**Controlador:**

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Project;
use App\Http\Requests\SaveProjectRequest;
use App\Events\ProjectSaved;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Intervention\Image\Facades\Image;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;

 public function store(SaveProjectRequest $request)
    {
        $project = new Project($request->validated()); /*Creamos una instancia del modelo "Proyectos" */
        $project->image = $request->file('image')->store('images');
        $project->save();

        /*Disparamos el evento*/
        ProjectSaved::dispatch($project);

        return redirect()->route('projects.index')->with('status', 'El proyecto fue creado con éxito');
    }
```

**Evento**

```
<?php

namespace App\Events;

use App\Project;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\Channel;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\InteractsWithSockets;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\PresenceChannel;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\PrivateChannel;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Broadcasting\ShouldBroadcast;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Events\Dispatchable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;

class ProjectSaved
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithSockets, SerializesModels;

    public $project;

    /**
     * Create a new event instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct(Project $project)
    {
        $this->project = $project;
    }

    /**
     * Get the channels the event should broadcast on.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Broadcasting\Channel|array
     */
    public function broadcastOn()
    {
        return new PrivateChannel('channel-name');
    }
}
```

**Listener**

```
<?php

namespace App\Listeners;

use App\Project;
use Intervention\Image\Facades\Image;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;
use App\Events\ProjectSaved;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Queue\InteractsWithQueue;

class OptimizeProjectImage
{
    /**
     * Create the event listener.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Handle the event.
     *
     * @param  ProjectSaved  $event
     * @return void
     */
    public function handle(ProjectSaved $event)
    {
        $image = Image::make(Storage::get($event->$project->image))
                ->widen(1000)
                ->encode(); /*Nueva img redimensionada a 1000px ancho y altura responsive, y volvemos a codificar la img(jpg.png...)*/
        /*Podemos bajar AÚN MÁS el peso de la imagen, usando el método "limitColors(255)" */

        Storage::put($event->$project->image, (string) $image); /*Reemplazaremos la imagen que tenemos almacenada, por la nueva, y lo forzamos a guardar en string*/
    }
}
```

*El error que me da es este: ErrorException
Undefined variable: project, y peta en el archivo del listener, en la línea 32, dónde uso $event->project->image.... en teoría usando $event puedo acceder en las propiedades, y he comprobado que en el Evento la variable project sea publica...*

---

**solución**
"($event->project... sin el $ " respuesta dada por *porloscerros*

Comment: `($event->project...` sin el $

Comment: Gracias @porloscerrosΨ, pero podrías explicarme por qué?

Comment: Porque `$event` es una instancia de tu clase `ProjectSaved`, que tiene una propiedad `$project`. Así cómo dentro de `ProjectSaved` te refieres a esa propiedad con `$this->project`, donde `$this` se refiere a la instancia de la clase, en el caso del listener has asignado esa instancia a la variable `$event`, entonces te refieres a ella con `$event->project `. Puedes leer más en [Propiedades](https://www.php.net/manual/es/language.oop5.properties.php)